Type library exporter warning for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'
I've searched and apart from switching the Range and Worksheet arguments to object then casting them back, is there a way to stop these warnings?

Warning: Type library exporter could not find the type library for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'
Warning: Type library exporter could not find the type library for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

The reference refers to the following nuget package: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15.0.4795.1001 
The full message is

'Warning: Type library exporter could not find the type library for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'.  IUnknown was substituted for the interface.'

The code causing the issue is:
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
' ...
Public Sub CreateCFTOutput(wsOutput As Worksheet, i As Integer, year As Integer, firstCell As Range, rtsInput As Range, fixedInterest As Range) _
    Implements IJupiterConnector.CreateCFTOutput
' ...

If it helps, this is the class definition:
<ComVisible(True), Guid("F264EE7A-8142-42BD-B513-3D98179EFA27"), 
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("comTWCF.JupiterConnector")> 
Public Class JupiterConnector Implements IJupiterConnector

And this is the interface definition:
<Guid("1075F14F-2D82-404E-9BEA-B82533471782"), 
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> 
Public Interface IJupiterConnector

Is there a way to resolve this? I've searched but cannot find a solution to this specific issue.

Where is IJupiterConnector.CreateCFTOutput defined? In a different assembly? If so, check the version of excel referenced by that assembly.

That's the COM interface for the class, same assembly, same namespace and same Interop reference. Question updated with class and interface definitions.

Why are you trying to create a COM library in the first place? Your COM library is trying to expose the .NET wrappers of the Excel COM interfaces. The tool creating the COM type library for your tool correctly tells you it can't find the COM definitions of those wrappers. If you want your COM library to return interfaces to some running Excel application and its objects, it should expose the Excel interfaces. Which is a bad idea anyway

What are you trying to build? Using the Excel application in a web app is a very bad idea. You'd need to not only install Excel on the server, you'd have to be extremely careful to start a new Excel instance per request and properly close it, otherwise you'd end up with hundreds of Excel instances eating up the server's memory. And you'd have to buy a license for every single remote user, whether anonymous or not. There are a lot of .NET libraries (both commercial and open source) that generate or read real Excel files without requiring Excel itself, like EPPlus, ClosedXML, SylvanXlsb

This application was written by an ex-developer for our Dutch business, and I've been tasked with trying to bring it up to date. I don't know the reasoning behind why it was done this way, I suspect it might be safer to leave it as is, no one wants to business test it as it is!

Microsoft recommends all such legacy apps to switch to supported approaches , so your company should consider that https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2
